# pam_access won't work when logging in with SSH CentOS

Tags: centos, sshd, pam

I am working on configuring access for my machine with PAM. I am using CentOS 7.6.1810 (core). I really want to use PAM because it will allow me to set users that can log in in exactly one place once it is set up by editing `/etc/security/access.conf`, which would be extremely convenient. I am also wanting to learn how PAM works, so I would rather not use another method, even though I know they exist. I currently have this working for users that log in using the tty, but I can't get it working with ssh.

Below I have shown the necessary configuration files.

In my `/etc/security/access.conf` file I have the following lines:

```
+:root:ALL
-:ALL:ALL
```

NOTE: I know that this is a security flaw, but I am just doing this while I am configuring my system. I will remove the top line.

In my `/etc/pam.d/systemauth` file I have the following:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so
account     required      pam_access.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

Specifically note the line that says `account require pam_access.so`. This should make it so that any policy that includes `system-auth` should use pam_access for authentication.

Here are the relevant lines from my `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file:

```
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
account    require      pam_access.so
account    include      password-auth
```

These lines should ensure that the ssh daemon uses pam_access for logging in.

Additionally, in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file I made sure that the line controlling whether to use pam is set correctly. Specifically I have the line `UsePAM yes`

Finally, when I try and log in from another account that isn't root using SSH to test whether this is working I get the following log output in `/var/log/secure`:

```
Oct  4 21:12:34 localhost sshd[3683]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for pbeesly from 10.0.2.2 port 45250 ssh2
Oct  4 21:12:34 localhost sshd[3683]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pbeesly by (uid=0)
```

I cannot understand why pam_access is not working. Perhaps I am missing something here, but I am new to system administration. Any help would be greatly appreciated!